# How to combine numerical and symbolic variables in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I've been trying to calculate and plot trajectories for orbital motion, but got stuck with the variable types.

All input variables are of *double* type, as well as the desired output. As a consequence, variables of orbital system (the ones with "_orb" in the names) are of *double* type. 
Here's the script. The diffficulties start from "Velocity corrections" part, in which I want to calculate minimum for a function of velocity change:

```
function trajectory_final (x0, y0 , z0, vx0, vy0, vz0, q0, q1, q2, q3)

o = 0.00114;
xk = 0;
yk = -150;
zk = 150;
double t;
%% Coordinate system transition:
x0_orb = (1 - 2*q2*q2 - 2*q3*q3)*x0 + 2*(q1*q2 + q0*q3)*y0 + 2*(q1*q3 - q0*q2)*z0;
y0_orb = 2*(q1*q2 - q0*q3)*x0 + (1 - 2*q1*q1 - 2*q3*q3)*y0 + 2*(q2*q3 + q0*q1)*z0;
z0_orb = 2*(q1*q3 + q0*q2)*x0 + 2*(q2*q3 - q0*q1)*y0 + (1 - 2*q1*q1 - 2*q2*q2)*z0;

vx0_orb = (1 - 2*q2*q2 - 2*q3*q3)*vx0 + 2*(q1*q2 + q0*q3)*vy0 + 2*(q1*q3 - q0*q2)*vz0;
vy0_orb = 2*(q1*q2 - q0*q3)*vx0 + (1 - 2*q1*q1 - 2*q3*q3)*vy0 + 2*(q2*q3 + q0*q1)*vz0;
vz0_orb = 2*(q1*q3 + q0*q2)*vx0 + 2*(q2*q3 - q0*q1)*vy0 + (1 - 2*q1*q1 - 2*q2*q2)*vz0;
%% Velocity corrections:

vx1 = sym('(xk - x0_orb - (6*o*t - 6*sin(o*t))*y0_orb - (-2*cos(o*t)/o + 2/o)*((-3*cos(o*t) + 4)*y0_orb - yk))/(4*sin(o*t)/o - 3*t - (2*cos(o*t)/o - 2/o)*(2*cos(o*t)/o - 2/o))');
vy1 = sym('(-3*cos(o*t) + 4)*y0_orb + (2*cos(o*t)/o - 2/o)*vx1 - yk');
vz1 = sym('(zk - (cos(o*t))*z0_orb)/(sin(o*t)/o)');


dvx = vx1 - vx0_orb;
dvy = vy1 - vy0_orb;
dvz = vz1 - vz0_orb;

total = sqrt((dvx)^2 + (dvy)^2 + (dvz)^2);
D = diff(total);
D_math = matlabFunction(D);
root = fzero(D_math, 600);
```

However, several problems occur:

1) If I run it as is now, variables in *vx1, vy1* and *vz1* are not replaced with their values assigned at launch, resulting in "Not enough input arguments" for fzero.

2) If I make *vx1, vy1* and *vz1* numerical, the error "Undefined function or variable t" appears;

3) If I make *vx1, vy1* and *vz1* numerical AND assign boundaries for t, then I cannot find root for D_math function on the desired interval.

Could you please tell me what is the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: Welcome on SO, please read [ask], it is unclear what your desired input /output behavior is, add an minimal example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing, added some further information on the desired solution.

Comment: Why are you using symbolic math at all? It's likely not needed if your end goal is to use `fzero` for *numerical* root finding. And I don't see where assign `vx1` etc. at launch. Also, `double t;` does not make any sense here as it's equivalent to `double('t');`.